# Set read only connection to duckdb in dbeaver

Tags: dbeaver, duckdb

I'm working in python with duckdb and would like to use dbeaver alongside in read only mode. Where in dbeaver can I alter the config for duckdb, it doesn't appear in same location as Postgres ?

What I've tried:

- Create data in python close connection and can then access duckdb via dbeaver
- Create data in python with config `READ_WRITE` then open dbeaver and get error on access about file lock

Answer (score 8):

In DBeaver edit connection. From Connection settings, select Driver properties tab. Right click, add new property with name duckdb.read_only and set value to true.

You can now work in DBeaver.

You may only do multiple read connections. Once reading, I dont think you'r allowed connect with read_write intentions.

DBeaver driver documentation links to https://duckdb.org/docs/api/java

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Olavz is correct, but it is not possible to open both a write connection and a read-only connection at the same time.
You can try in python:

```
rw = duckdb.connect("my.duckdb")
ro = duckdb.connect("my.duckdb", read_only=True)
```

Which will result in the error:

```
Error: Connection Error: Can't open a connection to same database file with a different configuration than existing connections
```

You can only open multiple read-only connections when there are no read-write connections.